# C#: Docking label at middle bottom of panel and have it grow with content on run time.

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, docking

I need a label to appear in the middle bottom (like 30px above the bottom line) of a panel, that also auto sizes to wrap the text depending on how long the text is.

So far I can only have the label auto size to wrap the text and have it docked at the bottom. But it is at bottom left and not middle.
As is on this example [Long Text Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PGQO.jpg) and [Image of short text I'd like to center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCvin.jpg)
(*sorry the text is not clear but its at the bottom in white*)

I was able to achieve the auto size using the ClientSizeChanged event as below.

```
private void Panel1_ClientSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label8.MaximumSize = new Size((sender as Control).ClientSize.Width - label8.Left, 10000);
    }
```

How do I have the text at the middle? It should be able to maintain the bottom middle (dock) position as I resize the panel.

Comment: Can't you use Dock= Bottom and TextAlign = MiddleCenter/BottomCenter?

Comment: @PablonotPicasso it doesn't work if the autosize property is set to true and I need to autosize on.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

To your panel add TableLayoutPanel with following Properties:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.AutoSize = true; // This can be set at the end if you use designer
tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 1;
tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;
tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Bottom;
panel1.Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel1); // add TableLayoutPanel to your panel
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label1, 0, 0); // Add your label to TableLayout
```

And set properties on Label:

```
label1.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom;
label1.AutoSize = true;
label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

Now you can set

```
tableLayoutPanel1.AutoSize = true;
```

It is kind of tricky but should give you what you need.